# Named Credential Invalid Hostname

Tags: apex, namedcredentials

I am trying to use named credentials as one of my endpoints has an underscore but I am running into this error:

```
FATAL_ERROR System.CalloutException: Invalid characters in hostname
```

Here is my actual code within the apex class:

```
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('callout:snowflake/api/v2/statements');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', token);
        req.setHeader('X-Snowflake-Authorization-Token-Type', 'KEYPAIR_JWT');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setBody(String.valueOf(JSON.serialize(wrapper)));
        system.debug(req);
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
        System.debug(res);
```

And here is how the named credential looks like:

label: snowflake

name: snowflake

URL: something_something.snowflakecomputing.com

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Hey @identigral I tried that and no luck, I should mention that I am trying this on a scratch org

Comment: You can switch your underscores to hyphens and Snowflake will interpret them on their platform. https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-connect--when-your-Snowflake-account-name-has-underscore-as-the-character

Comment: That did the trick, thank you!